# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024882, 'Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.', None, None)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, automation, pywin32

When I try to fetch around 250k rows from pgsql to excel  using pythons pywin32 package

I get the following error

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024882, 'Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.', None, None)

Comment: Not sure where this occurs (*pgsql* or *excel* although I tend to think it's the latter), or how memory is handled, but the obvious thing to do is break the lines in smaller chunks (e.g. 10k elements).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem while loading a sheet of 92,875 X 60 in size. It worked just fine before this sheet grew so large.

I figured out a way to fix this problem, which is quite simple. Instead of loading the whole range of data, read a single row and then another.

For example, my code was originally like this:

```
finalrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(win32com.client.constants.xlUp).Row
finalcell = '$%s$%s' % (finalcolumn, finalrow)
r = ws.Range('$A$1:' + finalcell).Value
rows = list(r)
```

where finalcolumn is a constant value, say 'BH'.

Changed to:

```
finalrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(win32com.client.constants.xlUp).Row
finalcell = '$%s$%s' % (finalcolumn, finalrow)
rows = []
for i in range(finalrow):
    r = ws.Range('$A$%s:$%s$%s' % (i+1, finalcolumn, i+1)).Value
    rows += list(r)
```

No significant performance hit was observed.